# Why does overriding the position variable of my SKSpriteNode subclass slow things down so much?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu) there is a cool function called `penDown` which causes your sprite to trace a line of some color across the screen whenever it moves from A to B. I wanted to recreate this behavior by subclassing `SKSpriteNode` and getting notified whenever the position changes. However, this simple override is causing the whole thing to slow down a ton (FPS drops from 20 to 7 with only two sprites):

```
override var position : CGPoint {
    get {
        return super.position
    }
    set {
        super.position = newValue
        // Add this new point to the bezier path of the line so that I can trace it.
    }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure it's the override that's causing the slow down and it's not from adding each point to a bezier path and then rendering it?

Comment: @MikeS Yes, because I don't actually do anything yet. It's literally what you see here: just a comment.

Comment: ok, just checking :)

Comment: Have you tried using [property observers](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_378) instead? `override var position : CGPoint { didSet { // ... } }`

Comment: @MikeS Ohhh my that is exactly what I needed--didn't affect FPS at all. Feel free to answer that so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you should be using [property observers](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_378) instead of overriding `get` and `set`.

```
override var position : CGPoint {
    didSet {
        // Add this new point to the bezier path of the line so that I can trace it.
    }
}
```